# Two trains and a bird

Tags: python

I have to create a code for the classic physics problem. link to the problem's explanation: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171224103032/http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.fly.trains.html)
but in my code, the user inputs the speed of the trains, the distance between them and the speed of the bird.It needs to output the total distance traveled by the bird and the trains and the birds' position each 0,01 second. Below is my code and I want some help on improving it.

```
t=0
v1= input ("Insert the trains' speed= ")
d= input ("Insert the distance between the trains= ")
va= input ("Insert the bird's speed= ")

v1= float(v1)
d=float(d)
va=float(va)

s1=0
s2=d

while s1<=s2:
 s1= v1*t
 s2=d-v1*t
 sa=va*t
 t1=d/(2*v1)
 da=t1*va
 tx1= ("Position of train 1= %sm")
 tx2= ("Position of train 2= %sm")
 tx3= ("Bird's position= %sm")
 print(tx1 % s1)
 print(tx2 % s2)
 print(tx3 % sa)
  t=t+0.01


if s1==s2:
 print ("The bird died")
 txt4=("Total distance traveled by the bird= %sm")
 print (txt4 % da)
```

Comment: What kind of improvement? In terms of reducing the number of lines?

Comment: When I run it, depending on the numbers that I input, the trains never meet. So, the line "the bird died" is never outputted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the bird is dead. Here is how it dies. The main modification is `if abs(s1-s2) < 1e-8:` to make your code work. The problem was that when `s1` and `s2` were getting equal, the condition `if s1==s2:` was not working because it was comparing numbers which were something like `14.9999999` and `15.0000000` which are though equal but represented in marginally different floating points. The simple solution for this is to check if the absolute difference between these two numbers is below some very small number such as `1e-8`.

I also added a `break` in your code when the bird dies to come out of the loop. In case you don't want this, just remove it. I also shortened your code by removing unnecessary lines required for printing.

```
while s1<=s2:
    s1 = v1*t
    s2 = d-v1*t
    sa = va*t
    t1 = d/(2*v1)
    da = t1*va
    print("Position of train 1 = %s m"%s1)
    print("Position of train 2 = %s m"%s2)
    print("Bird's position = %s m"%sa)
    t=t+0.01

    if abs(s1-s2) < 1e-8:
        print ("The bird died")
        print("Total distance traveled by the bird= %s m" %da)
        break
```

**Output**

```
Insert the trains' speed= 30
Insert the distance between the trains= 30
Insert the bird's speed= 20

Position of train 1 = 0.0 m
Position of train 2 = 30.0 m
Bird's position = 0.0 m
.
.
.
Bird's position = 10.000000000000004 m
The bird died
Total distance traveled by the bird= 10.0 m
```

Comment: omg thank you so much S2

Comment: You are welcome. The bird can rest in peace now

Answer (score 0):

In general, when doing comparisons between floating point numbers you want to avoid testing for exact equality.

For example, here you probably would like `s1==s2` to return `True` when comparing, say, `2.001010191012393 == 2.001010191012394`.

In this case, you could solve this by using `if s1>=s2` instead of `if s1==s2`.

You could also use an `else` in the `while` like this,

```
x, y = 1, 5
while x<y:
    x = x + 1
    print x
else:
    print "done"
```

More generally (that is, when the comparison is not one sided) you can use an expression like `abs(s2-s1)<epsilon`, where `epsilon` is an appropriately small number.  In your case, this is a bit difficult because `epsilon` will be a function of the parameters in your simulation, and probably much larger than the machine precision but related instead to your timestep (`0.01`, in your case).  Therefore, the one-sided inequality is better and easier.